# Merge and rebase issues due to GitHub using "main" and me still stuck with older git with "master"

Tags: git, github, version-control

GitHub has started using "main" as the main branch. I am however using an older version of git so whenever I initialize a repo it defaults to the "master" branch.

I created a repo on GitHub. Initialized it with a README. Then on my local machine, I created a bunch of files -> `git init` -> `git add .` -> `git commit -m "first commit` and then `git push -u origin master`.

Unfortunately it made a new `master` branch and pushed the files there.

I realized my mistake and thought I'd rename my **local** "master" branch to "main". Delete the **remote** master branch. Pull the README file to **local** "main" and then push.

- I renamed my local master by `git branch -m master main`
- Deleted remote master by `git push origin --delete master`
- Then I tried `git pull` which gave me the error -

```sh
$ git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

Tried pushing anyways -

```sh
$ git push -u origin main
Username for 'https://github.com': xxxx
Password for 'https://xxxx@github.com': 
To https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I tried some commands based on my Google search as follows but all of them failed -

```sh
$ git remote prune origin
```

Nothing changed.

```sh
$  git pull --rebase
```

Nothing changed
Then I did `git status` and based on its recommendation I tried -

```sh
$ git branch --unset-upstream
```

Then when I did `git pull` I get -

```sh
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> main
```

I feel lost now. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Is there a way for me to avoid this from happening again with newer projects. I mean, I cannot upgrade my git version. So for a new project the same issue will happen. Is it possible to do something so that I don't have to worry about this situation happening again?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I got it working by doing -

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

But when you do `git pull` you will get the following -

```
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 1.05 KiB | 537.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://github.com/xxx/xxx
   xxx...xxx  main       -> origin/main
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Which can be solved by

```
$ git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Since I had just started with the project, so there were not a lot of commits and history. I do not know how this will behave in larger projects, but for those who are starting out this may work.

Answer (score 0):

You have numerous options, but the simplest by far is to *discard the initial commit that GitHub made* that contains a `README` and/or `LICENSE` and so on.

Note that doing this requires a `git push --force` or `git push --force-with-lease`.  If anyone else has had access to the GitHub repository, and may have put additional commits on `main` on GitHub, discarding that initial commit on `main` requires discarding this these additional commits as well.

To discard that initial commit and use the name `main`, simply rename your own local branch first:

```
git branch -m master main
```

then use `git push --force` to send your commits to GitHub and *command* them to *discard* their commits in favor of yours:

```
git push -f -u origin main
```

If you prefer the name `master`, you don't need any forcing options: just push your `master` to the GitHub site under the name `master`, then have the GitHub system delete the name `main` there:

```
git push -u origin master
git push origin :main         # or git push --delete origin main
```

Then, go to the GitHub web interface and set the *default* name for clones to `master` rather than `main` (find "settings" on the top right, then "branches" along the left edge, to get to this page from the web interface).

If you wish to replace your initial commit with a commit that adds on to the initial GitHub commit containing a `README`, you can use `git rebase`.  Here's an example:

```
[created "test-rebase-init-commit" repository on GitHub w/ README]
$ cd /tmp && mkdir test-rebase-init-commit && cd test-rebase-init-commit
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo sample file data > sample-file
$ git add sample-file
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 08681e0] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 sample-file
```

Note how this created a branch named `master`.  We now rename it `main` (we could have done this first, the situation would be the same either way):

```
$ git branch -m main
$ git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/[me]/test-rebase-init-commit
$ git fetch
warning: no common commits
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 601 bytes | 120.00 KiB/s, done.
From ssh://github.com/chris3torek/test-rebase-init-commit
 * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
```

As you can see, we now have two unrelated histories (each consisting of one commit): mine starts and ends with commit `08681e0`, and theirs (GitHub's) starts and ends with a different commit, whose hash ID is not seen here.  We can find it with `git log --all`; adding `--graph` shows that the commits aren't related.  I won't include the output but the hash ID of "their" commit is `589a046...` (I've snipped the rest; your commits will have different IDs anyway) and its log message is `Initial commit`, vs mine which is the even-lazier `initial`.

Now, in my case, I'm "lucky": I have no file conflicts with their initial commit.  (This is not luck, of course: I knew exactly what I was doing and therefore did not create a README file.)  So I can now run:

```
$ git rebase origin/main
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/main.
```

A new `git log --all --graph` shows that I now have one commit, with a different hash ID—it begins with `0f2ce55` in this case—that has, as its parent, "their" commit `589a046`.  So now `git push -u origin main` works fine:

```
$ git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 297 bytes | 99.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To ssh://github.com/[me]/test-rebase-init-commit
   589a046..0f2ce55  main -> main
Branch 'main' set up to track remote branch 'main' from 'origin'.
```

(I've deleted the test repository before posting this, so there's no point looking for it now.)